# Add Postage and Packaing to Paypal link HTML

Tags: html, paypal

Im trying to add postage and packaing on top of a href link for paypal so far I have this:

```
<a href="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?business=needemail@paypal.com&cmd=_xclick&currency_code=GBP&amount=13.50&item_name=Blue/Pink%20Wallpaper%20SKU%20LU%20W4"> Buy now </a>
```

However wish to add postage and packaing into the code but not sure what / where to add...?

Answer (score 0):

Dont worry found out by adding &shipping=4.95 to the html code it adds shipping.